# Flutter firestore string convert to document reference for where clause

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My chat collection has a field event_id and its type is reference now I want to use my events document id for query how can I convert string to DocumentReference type so I can pass into where clause and query through the chat collection

chat.where('event_id', isEqualTo:'events/J3HTFRpL0H').snapshots(),

Comment: I request you to please share detailed structure of your collection.

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried so far, and your collection's structure as mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is already a DocumentReference, you can simply do `eventRef.snapshots()`, assuming `eventRef` is the DocumentReference to the event.

If the data you get for the event reference is a String, you need to cast it as a DocumentReference first, e.g., `eventRef = eventStr as DocumentReference;`, assuming `eventStr` is the string that represents the DocumentReference to the event document.

Comment: so if eventString = 'events/JSDFIJLI' it can be cast using above?

Comment: Yes. The event document id is actually the part after the '/'. In this case, it is 'JSDFIJLI'. You could either construct a DocumentReference using the event document id like so: FirebaseFireStore.instance.collection('events').doc('JSDFIJLI'), or you can cast the event reference string as a DocumentReference like so: eventRef = 'events/JSDFIJLI' as DocumentReference. Either way, it should work.